# Circular standard deviation to moving window in R

Tags: r, time-series, angle, moving-average

I am trying to calculate the circular standard deviation of a circular variable (compass bearing, in 360 degrees) in a moving window using `rollapply` function from `zoo` package on a large time series.

To check if the results I obtained on the full dataset are correct, I created a dummy dataframe with 41 observations with similar bearing (around N). Then I calculated the circular sd using `sd.circular` from the `circular` package, and I obtain a result that looks about right (sd= 0.2069542 radians).

Then I applied `sd.circular` function to the 41 observation using `rollapply` with width=41, and I was expecting to obtain the same result as before. However, in this case, the result is totally different (and likely wrong, sd=2.551602 radians). I also tried to use the source code of `sd.circular` inside `rollapply`, but I obtained the same result. Does someone know what am I doing wrong and how can I correctly apply `sd.circular` to a moving window?

Code from the example

```
library(zoo)
library(circular)
angle<-c(1:10,330:360)
angle<-as.data.frame(angle)
angle$angle<-circular(angle$angle,type="angles",units="degrees",rotation="clock")
sd.circular(angle$angle) 
rollapply(angle$angle,width=41,FUN=sd.circular,align="center")
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

**1)** The attributes are stripped so add them back in:

```
sd.circ <- function(x, attr) {
  attributes(x) <- attr
  sd.circular(x)
}

rollapply(angle$angle, 41, sd.circ, attr = attributes(angle$angle))
```

**2)** Alternately, run `rollapply` over the indexes instead of the data:

```
sd.circ.ix <- function(x, ix) sd.circular(x[ix])
rollapply(seq_along(angle$angle), 41, sd.circ.ix, x = angle$angle)
```